# Возможно ли зафиксировать элемент и при этом сделать его блочным

Tags: css3, html5

```
<ul style='overflow-y: auto;'>
  <li>Шапка</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
<ul>
```

То есть в списке зафиксировать шапку, остальные строчки сделать как скролинг. Шапка должна быть блочной, так как не знаем ее высоты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
ul {
  height: 7em;
  overflow: auto;
  line-height: 2;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

li:first-child {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Шапка</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
  <li>Список</li>
<ul>
```

Comment: Я шел к этому, но очень долго ;)

Answer (score 1):

Еще вариант, правда с другой структурой в html

```css
.block {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.block__title {
  background-color: #bbb;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}

.block__list {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="block">
  <h2 class="block__title">Шапка</h2>
  <ul class="block__list">
    <li class="block__list-item">Элемент</li>
    <li class="block__list-item">Элемент</li>
    <li class="block__list-item">Элемент</li>
    <li class="block__list-item">Элемент</li>
    <li class="block__list-item">Элемент</li>
    <li class="block__list-item">Элемент</li>
    <li class="block__list-item">Элемент</li>
    <li class="block__list-item">Элемент</li>
    <li class="block__list-item">Элемент</li>
    <li class="block__list-item">Элемент</li>
    <li class="block__list-item">Элемент</li>
    <li class="block__list-item">Элемент</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```